# There is an error loading static content in multi module project with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, weblogic, multi-module

I have multi module project with Spring boot and an external server Weblogic.
These are modules:

- dao
- service
- web

  **pom.xml** (dao) .

It is the work with database (repository, entities)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>gov-multiple-modules</artifactId>
        <groupId>gov</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <groupId>com.dao</groupId>
    <artifactId>dao</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <output.directory.jdbc.oracle>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</output.directory.jdbc.oracle>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${output.directory.jdbc.oracle}/lib/ojdbc6.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF8</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

- pom.xml (service )

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>gov-multiple-modules</artifactId>
        <groupId>gov</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dao</groupId>
            <artifactId>dao</artifactId>
            <version>${version.dao.module}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${version.mapstruct}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
          <plugins>

              <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                  <configuration>
                      <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF8</argLine>
                  </configuration>
              </plugin>

            <plugin> 
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.apache.maven.plugins}</version>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${version.mapstruct}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

- pom.xml (web )

  It is the work with requests from clients (Contoroller and RestControllers).

There is an entry point in app.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>gov-multiple-modules</artifactId>
        <groupId>gov</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>web</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>service</artifactId>
            <version>${version.service.module}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>weblogic-war-gov</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF8</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin> <!--It is for convert beans-->
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.apache.maven.plugins}</version>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${version.mapstruct}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

- pom.xml (parrent)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <modules>
        <module>dao</module>
        <module>service</module>
        <module>web</module>
    </modules>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>gov</groupId>
    <artifactId>gov-multiple-modules</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>gov-multiple-modules</name>
    <description>project with Spring Boot for multiple module applications</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <version.apache.maven.plugins>3.8.1</version.apache.maven.plugins>
        <version.mapstruct>1.3.0.Final</version.mapstruct>

        <version.apache.common.lang3>3.9</version.apache.common.lang3>
        <version.apache.commons.text>1.8</version.apache.commons.text>
        <version.apache.commons.beanutils>1.9.4</version.apache.commons.beanutils>
        <version.hibernate.validator>6.0.17.Final</version.hibernate.validator>
        <version.reflection>0.9.11</version.reflection>
        <version.dao.module>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version.dao.module>
        <version.service.module>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version.service.module>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--This artifact need for testing that to find classes into classpath-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <version>${version.reflection}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${version.apache.common.lang3}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>${version.apache.commons.text}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>${version.apache.commons.beanutils}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

An entry point

```java
@SpringBootConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.dao", "com.service"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.dao"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.service", "com.dao", "com.web"})
public class WebSpringBootJarApplication
        extends SpringBootServletInitializer
        implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER  = LoggerFactory.getLogger( WebSpringBootJarApplication.class );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebSpringBootJarApplication.class, args);
        LOGGER.info("Start an application...");
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        LOGGER.info("There is building the web application!");
        return builder.sources(WebSpringBootJarApplication.class);
    }
}
```

- src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/weblogic.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
        xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        https://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
        https://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.9/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

    <wls:context-root>sun</wls:context-root>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

After running I must see the page the greeting.

- com.web.controller.index.IndexController

```java
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

- src/main/resources/templates/index.html

But I get an error.

http://localhost:7001/sun/

- in an browser

> Error 500--Internal Server Error java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendContentError(ServletResponseImpl.java:738)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendError(ServletResponseImpl.java:796)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendError(ServletResponseImpl.java:713)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$ErrorWrapperResponse.sendErrorIfNecessary(ErrorPageFilter.java:349)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$ErrorWrapperResponse.getWriter(ErrorPageFilter.java:363)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$StaticView.render(ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.java:227)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118)

- in console IDE

> > -"[2020-03-11 08:53:30,118] Artifact web:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully [2020-03-11 08:53:30,119] Artifact web:war
> >     exploded: Deploy took 14,724 milliseconds
> >     --11-03-2020 08:53:30.612 - INFO  17568   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet
> >     'dispatcherServlet'  -"--11-03-2020 08:53:30.613  -DEBUG  17568 
> >       o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected
> >     StandardServletMultipartResolver  -"--11-03-2020
> >     08:53:30.621  -DEBUG  17568   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        :
> >     enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers
> >     will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
> >     -"--11-03-2020 08:53:30.621   - INFO  17568   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization
> >     in 8 ms  -"--11-03-2020 08:53:30.624  -DEBUG  17568 
> >       o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/sun/", parameters={}
> >     -"--11-03-2020 08:53:30.628   -DEBUG  17568   s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to
> >     com.web.controller.index.IndexController#index()  -"--11-03-2020
> >     08:53:30.647  -DEBUG  17568   o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver :
> >     Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg,
> >     */*;q=.2]  -"--11-03-2020 08:53:30.647    -DEBUG  17568   o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : View name 'index', model
> >     {}  -"--11-03-2020 08:53:30.652   -DEBUG  17568 
> >       o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : Forwarding to [index] 
> >     -"--11-03-2020 08:53:30.653   -DEBUG  17568   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "FORWARD" dispatch for GET
> >     "/sun/index", parameters={}  -"--11-03-2020 08:53:30.656  -DEBUG  17568 
> >       o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to
> >     ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/",
> >     "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/",
> >     "/"]  -"--11-03-2020 08:53:30.657 -DEBUG  17568 
> >       o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found 
> >     -"--11-03-2020 08:53:30.657   -DEBUG  17568   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "FORWARD"
> >     dispatch, status 404  -"--11-03-2020 08:53:30.664 -DEBUG  17568 
> >       o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Error rendering view
> >     [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'index'; URL
> >     [index]]
> >      - java.lang.NullPointerException: null   at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendContentError(ServletResponseImpl.java:738)
> >     ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.4]   at
> >     weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendError(ServletResponseImpl.java:796)
> >     ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.4]   at
> >     weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendError(ServletResponseImpl.java:713)
> >     ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.4]   at
> >     org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$ErrorWrapperResponse.sendErrorIfNecessary(ErrorPageFilter.java:349)
> >     ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]    at
> >     org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$ErrorWrapperResponse.flushBuffer(ErrorPageFilter.java:343)
> >     ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]    at
> >     weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:336)
> >     ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.4]   at
> >     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:171)
> >     ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]  at
> >     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316)
> >     ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]  at
> >     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373)
> >     [spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]   at
> >     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118)
> >     [spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]   at
> >     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057)
> >     [spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]   at
> >     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
> >     [spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]   at
> >     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> >     [spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]   at
> >     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
> >     [spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]   at
> >     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
> >     [javax.servlet.javax.servlet-api.jar:3.1.0]   at
> >     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> >     [spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]   ...
>
> "java.lang.NullPointerException: null     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendContentError(ServletResponseImpl.java:738)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendError(ServletResponseImpl.java:796)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendError(ServletResponseImpl.java:713)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$ErrorWrapperResponse.sendErrorIfNecessary(ErrorPageFilter.java:349)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$ErrorWrapperResponse.flushBuffer(ErrorPageFilter.java:343)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:336)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:171)
>     ...
>
> --11-03-2020 08:53:30.666 -DEBUG  17568   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete
>   request: java.lang.NullPointerException  -"--11-03-2020
>   08:53:30.667  -ERROR  17568   o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  :
>   Forwarding to error page from request [/] due to exception [null]

It worked then the application was not multi module project.

Any ideas what the errors are? Please.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

I needed to add an dependency - the  thymeleaf. The static conten don't run without.

It need to add into  pom's web-module.

```xml
 <groupId>com.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>web</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```